# Real time motion detection and alarm generation using MATLAB

Tags: real-time, matlab

I am doing a project on real time motion detection for security purpose using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) with alarm generation. I had created code for live video capturing and saved it into an [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) file, but I am unable to read the live video in the code while it is running. Motion detection is not working properly. I have done this using two scripts. Two scripts are independently working, but when combined it is not reading live input. The scripts I used are posted below.

```
Enter code here 1. %code for reading and saving AVI file

function realtime_test()
    global movie name vid;
    % Define frame rate
    NumberFrameDisplayPerSecond=10;

    % Open figure
    hFigure=figure(1);

    % Set-up webcam video input

    vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1);

    % Set parameters for video
    % Acquire only one frame each time
    set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',1);
    % Go on forever until stopped
    set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
    % Get a grayscale image
    set(vid,'ReturnedColorSpace','rgb')
    vidRes = get(vid, 'VideoResolution');
    nBands = get(vid, 'NumberOfBands');
    hImage = imshow( zeros(vidRes(2), vidRes(1), nBands));
    preview(vid,hImage);
    triggerconfig(vid, 'Manual');

    % Set up timer object
    TimerData=timer('TimerFcn', {@FrameRateDisplay,vid},'Period',1/NumberFrameDisplayPerSecond,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','BusyMode','drop');
    name = 'Realtime';
    movie=avifile(name,'compression','none');

    % Start video and timer object
    start(vid);
    start(TimerData);

    % We go on until the figure is closed
    uiwait(hFigure);

    % Clean up everything
    stop(TimerData);
    delete(TimerData);
    stop(vid);
    delete(vid);
    movie = close(movie);
    % Clear persistent variables
    clear functions;


% This function is called by the timer to display one frame of the figure

function FrameRateDisplay(obj, event,vid)
    global movie frame;

    frame=uint8(getsnapshot(vid));
    movie=addframe(movie,frame);
    persistent IM;
    persistent handlesRaw;
    persistent handlesPlot;
    trigger(vid);
    IM=getdata(vid,1,'uint8');

    if isempty(handlesRaw)
       % if first execution, we create the figure objects
       subplot(2,1,1);
       handlesRaw=imagesc(IM);
       title('CurrentImage');

       % Plot first value
       Values=mean(IM(:));
       subplot(2,1,2);
       handlesPlot=plot(Values);
       title('Average of Frame');
       xlabel('Frame number');
       ylabel('Average value (au)');
    else
       % We only update what is needed
       set(handlesRaw,'CData',IM);
       Value=mean(IM(:));
       OldValues=get(handlesPlot,'YData');
       set(handlesPlot,'YData',[OldValues Value]);
    end
```

2.% code for motion detection

```
% This m-file implements the frame difference algorithm for background
% subtraction.

clear all;
close all;

% source = aviread('live.avi');
%source = aviread('test.avi');
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
   {'*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg;.*flv','Video Files (*.avi,*.mpg,*.mpeg,.*flv)';
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
  'Select a video file');

mov = mmreader(fullfile(pathname,filename));
implay(filename);
source = aviread(filename);
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

thresh = 50;

bg = source(1).cdata;           % Read in 1st frame as background frame
bg_bw = rgb2gray(bg);           % Convert background to greyscale

% ----------------------- Set frame size variables -----------------------
fr_size = size(bg);
width = fr_size(2);
height = fr_size(1);
fg = zeros(height, width);

% --------------------- Process frames -----------------------------------

for i = 2:45
    fr = source(i).cdata;       % Read in frame
    fr_bw = rgb2gray(fr);       % Convert frame to grayscale

    fr_diff = abs(double(fr_bw) - double(bg_bw));  % Cast operands as double to avoid negative overflow

    for j=1:width                 % If fr_diff > thresh pixel in foreground
        for k=1:height
            if ((fr_diff(k,j) > thresh))
                fg(k,j) = fr_bw(k,j);

                disp('motion detected');

                %------------------------- Executes alarm ---------------------------------

                  t = 15;
                  Fs = 50;
                  [t,Fs] = wavread('Blip.wav');
                  player = audioplayer(t,Fs);
                  play(player);

                %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            else
                fg(k,j) = 0;
            end
        end
        disp('motion not detected');
    end

    bg_bw = fr_bw;

    %figure(1), subplot(3,1,1), imshow(fr)
    subplot(3,1,2),imshow(fr_bw)
    subplot(3,1,3),imshow(uint8(fg))
    figure,imshow(uint8(fr_diff))

    %M(i-1)  = im2frame(uint8(fg),gray);        % Put frames into movie
end
fps = 15;
%movie2avi(M,'frame_difference_output', 'fps', 30);           % Save movie as AVI
```

Comment: Matlab and real time are not very good friends... why not Simulink? Or something else?

Comment: I am not familiar with simulink.Please tell me what to do

Comment: smulink is pretty user friendly, so building something should not be a big problem. Simulink itself has a real time toolbox, start from there. Still maybe in SO knows how to make something in matlab real time, and they may help you. tag the quiestion with real time also

Comment: thanks Anded Biguri....I will check it...please post if any furthur development is possible regarding this topic.

Comment: Do you mean nothing is displayed while running your code? That could be due to the fact that matlab waits with repainting till the current process is finished. You could force it with a `drawnow` and maybe even make a short `pause(0.1)` for refreshing the window - or use some additional software.

Comment: yaa its displaying results but real time video is not processed.What ever is recorded earlier is being processed.I want to combine both codes so that I can process real time videos.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading source in your second code you can directly read your live webcam using vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1). I think it will satisfy your requirements.Try out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this for security purposes, I guess that near-realtime should be good enough. 
Here is a process flow that should work. Note that the entities that I mention can be threads, cpu's or even computers, whatever suits you.

- Entity 1: Record a short fragment and save it (every 5 secs for example)
- Entity 2: Frequently check the latest fragment and analyse it, including the sending of a signal if required. (every second for example)

With the times I proposed, you won't get realtime results but the delay should be limited to a max of 6 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your reply...But I want to record and read the live video in same code as it is for security purpose.

Comment: @user2060681 I don't understand your reasoning. What makes 2 scripts less secure than one?